# How to get the path of folder in Azure Function C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, console-application

I have created 2 folders in  my project named `TempFile` and `TempFile\Sample`. Here is the folder structure

[image: here]

How can I get the path of this folder and the file SampleExcel.xlsx (`project\TempFile` and `project\TempFile\Sample\SampleExcel.xlsx` resp) using c#. Also once I publish it to Azure will I need to change it?

Here is what I have tried:

```cs
public void Run([QueueTrigger("my-queuename", Connection = "")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{    
    //Method 1            
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    //Method 2
    var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    //Method 3
    var filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"TempFile\Sample" + "\\SampleExcel.xlsx");           
}
```

The problem with these methods is that they return the path `project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`

How can I get the required path?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set  `Copy to Output Directory`  property of file to `CopyAlways`? Right click on the file in solution explorer, select properties

Comment: @viveka, did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: Yes @Prasad, but it i not working

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solution?

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem by using code as ` filePath1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\TempFile\\" + tempFile + ".xlsx";

                filePath2 = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\TempFile\\Sample\\SampleExcel.xlsx";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` as:

```
filePath1 = Environment.CurrentDirectory +"\\TempFile\\" + tempFile + ".xlsx"; 
filePath2 = Environment.CurrentDirectory +"\\TempFile\\Sample\\SampleExcel.xlsx";
```